# Ruby check if sentence has words from array which are bigram/trigram

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I want to check if a sentence has an array item, *which is a bigram/trigram*, from `words` array, and the bigram/trigram comprising the array item are together in the sentence.

`words = ["foo", "bar", "spooky", "rick james"]`
 `sentence = say hello to rick james but not rick and james`

Since `rick james` is an array item and is **together**,
Expected output should be

```
false #say
false #hello
false #to
true #rick <---
true #james <---
false #but
false #not
false #rick <---
false #and
false #james <---
```

I tried this

```
# BASIC EXAMPLE
words = ["foo", "bar", "spooky", "rick james"]

sentence = "something spooky rick this way comes, rick james"

sentence.split.each {|s| puts words.include?(s) }

# OUTPUT                      #EXPECTED OUTPUT
false #something              false
true #spooky <---             true  #spooky
false #rick                   false  #rick
false #this                   false
false #way                    false
false #comes                  false
false #rick                   true  #rick <---
false #james                  true  #james <---
```

What to modify to include the expected output

Comment: why not `words.each { |w| p sentence.include?(w) }`?

Comment: The way you split `sentence` won't match with `"rick james"`.

Answer (score 2):

If your domain is bigrams/trigrams you should split the sentence to bigrams/trigrams.

[Enumareable#each_cons(n)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) might help you (I'll take n=2 for bigrams)

```
sentence = "say hello to rick james but not rick and james"
split.each_cons(2) {|e| puts "#{e.join(" ")}" }

# say hello
# hello to
# to rick
# rick james
# james but
# but not
# not rick
# rick and
# and james
```

And if bi/trigrams are included as a whole, it means its lexems are also included.

```
words = ["foo", "bar", "spooky", "rick james"]   
sentence.split.each_cons(2) do |e| 
  puts "#{e} => #{words.include?(e)||words.include?(e.join(" "))}"
end

# ["say", "hello"] => false
# ["hello", "to"] => false
# ["to", "rick"] => false
# ["rick", "james"] => true
# ["james", "but"] => false
# ["but", "not"] => false
# ["not", "rick"] => false
# ["rick", "and"] => false
# ["and", "james"] => false
```

then you can take those array elements and return true/flase for each of them

Comment: The sentence needs to be split in unigrams, the way suggested in the ques. If sentence has matching tri or bi word phrases, it needs to be `true` for each corresponding uni gram words when split. Checking them for tri/bi/uni in that order wud be too consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can search (.include?) or (.include_in?) the sentence for each word in the array. This way you will search for .include?("rick james")